# Ionic 2 App - Not making any Ajax calls via IOS Simulator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been trying to run this app through simulator.

When I run **ionic emulate ios**, this app will not make any Ajax Calls

When I run **ionic emulate ios -c -l** this app works perfectly

This is my provider class which I copied pretty much exactly from the Ionic Conference App

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Storage,SqlStorage} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

/*
  Generated class for the RafitoData provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RafitoData {
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  } 
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.districts = null;
    this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
  }


addCustomer(customer) {
    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {

      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

      var partialURL = '/rafitows/userInfo/create';
      var body = JSON.stringify(customer);
      // We're using Angular Http provider to request the data,
      // then on the response it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
      this.http.post(partialURL,body,{headers:headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data.status);
        }, err=> {console.log(err)});
    });
  }
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I have the cordova whitelist plugin.

This is my ionic information:

```
Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

I have uploaded the whole project on gitHub

https://github.com/alyn000r/testAjax/tree/master/testAjax

Comment: what errors are in the error log of the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below line to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Also have a look [here](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I did do this, this does not help :(